# Unable to read Java classes when running scripts from Karate UI

Tags: karate

I'm using Java util classes for defining constants and helper functions.

From my feature file, I can call something like:

```
Java.type('com.somecompany.api.utils.Helpers').generateCustomEmail("NZ")
```

and it works.

But when I'm running my script from Karate UI, I get:

> javascript evaluation failed:
>   Java.type('com.somecompany.api.utils.Helpers').generateCustomEmail("NZ"),
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.somecompany.api.utils.Helpers

I'm using karate-0.8.0.1.jar for Karate UI. I open my scripts by loading the root directory of my project in Karate UI.

Am I loading my scripts wrong? All other statements apart from the Java class calls are working in Karate UI.

Answer (score 0):

Launch the Karate UI from *within* your Java project in the IDE. Here is an example: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Karate-UI#java-api

```
import com.intuit.karate.ui.App;
import org.junit.Test;

public class CatsUiRunner {

    @Test
    public void testApp() {
        App.run("src/test/java/demo/cats/cats.feature", "dev");
    }    

}
```